# To improve \check symbol in math mode and unify it with \hat

Tags: math-mode, accents

For some reasons I need `\check{symbol}` as well as `\hat{symbol}` in the same expression for different symbols. But the accent in `\check{symbol}` looks not identically as in `\hat` (much worse!) and prints it at another height.

So I need them in unified style and at the same place above the same symbol.

I tried to play with rotatebox and `\lefteqn` like this

```
$\lefteqn{\smash{\raisebox{12.32pt}{\rotatebox{180}{$\hat{\phantom{s}}$}}}}s\hat{s}$
```

or

```
$\lefteqn{{\kern 0.5pt}\smash{\raisebox{12.32pt}{\rotatebox{180}{$\hat{\hphantom{s}}$}}}}s\hat{s}$
```

with 10pt declaration of the main text:

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

But the horizontal problem is that `\hat{\phantom{s}}` (version 2)writes hat 
centered with respect to the bar of `\phantom{s}` while the true `\hat{s}` prints it centered to the head of 's'.

And of course, the vertical raisebox parameter is sensitive to the kind of letter.

My question: how to organize such 'improved' check accent as a command (in ideal, not just for the specified by hand symbol like my 's') which replaces hat in `\hat{}` by rotated hat at the SAME place?

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Comment: Try moving the center of rotation using the optional argument of \rotatebox.